# Lock record before updating?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

Is there any disadvantage of locking a record before updating it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, what do you mean my "locking"?

But generally, yes.  What you're probably talking about is "[pessimistic locking](http://www.redhat.com/docs/manuals/jboss/jboss-eap-4.2/doc/Server_Configuration_Guide/TransactionJTA_Overview-Pessimistic_and_optimistic_locking.html)", and the disadvantage is that your scalability can be negatively impacted.